# Does the execute bit grant any security for a readable binary file?

Tags: unix, file-permissions

If a user of a UNIX system has permission to read (but not to write or execute) a binary file can't they just make an executable copy of it?

If a file is readable by a user that either

1. owns at least one accessible directory (and can, therefore, set its permissions freely) or
2. owns at least one accessible file (and can, therefore, set its permissions freely) or
3. has access to at least one file that is writable and executable,

is there anything preventing this user from making an executable copy of the file they want to execute and then executing it?

Assuming the user satisfies neither (1) nor (2) nor (3), can they still somehow execute a binary file they can only read?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But they can't escalate their privileges in any way do to that. Most critically, they can't make use of the setuid bit.

What is more interesting is the converse, which is that a file can be executable but not readable. That creates a security difference, provided you're on a system that does not permit you to always read memory of processes you launch.